# XML::twig to filter XML parent nodes in PERL

Tags: perl, xml-twig

I have a xml snippet

```
<head>
 <a>
   <b  attr_1=1>
   <b  attr_1=2>
     <c  attr_2 =3  attr_3 =5/>
     <c  attr_2 =4  attr_3 =6 />
  </b>
 </a>
<a>
   <b  attr_1=1/>
   <b  attr_1=3>
     <c  attr_2 =3  attr_3 =5/>
     <c  attr_2 =10  attr_3 =10/ >
   </b>
 </a>
</head>
```

Now only those  node are legitimate which have `<b attr_1 =3>`(at least one) and at least one respective child `<c>` having `attr_2=10` and `attr_3 =10` is there.
Thus the ouput file should have following trade

```
   <a>
       <b  attr_1=1/>
       <b  attr_1=3>(this is the legitimate value)
         <c  attr_2 =3  attr_3 =5/>
         <c  attr_2 =10  attr_3 =10/ >(this is the legitimate combination)
       </b>  
   </a>
```

My Code is

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = new XML::Twig( twig_handlers => { a=> \&a} );
$twig->parsefile('1511.xml');
$twig->set_pretty_print('indented');
$twig->print_to_file('out.xml');

    sub a {

        my ( $twig, $a ) = @_ ;

        $a->cut
         unless grep { $_->att( 'attr_1' ) eq '3' } $a->children( 'b' )

    }
```

By this I am able to go till level . Please help if anybody can  in explaining how to traverse and grep till node C which is inside node B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had some errors in your XML-file. Also you seem to have deleted some parts of your description. You can also set some attribute restrictions to handlers and the `*child` methods.

```
sub a {

  my ( $twig, $a ) = @_ ;
  my $cut = 1;

  foreach my $b ($a->children('b[@attr_1="3"]')){
    $cut &&= not grep {$_->att('attr_2') eq '10'
                   and $_->att('attr_3') eq '10'} $b->children('c');
  }


  $a->cut if $cut;
}
```

This is the file I used for testing:

```
<head>
<a>
   <b  attr_1="1" />
   <b  attr_1="2">
     <c  attr_2 ="3"  attr_3 ="5"/>
     <c  attr_2 ="4"  attr_3 ="6" />
  </b>
</a>
<a>
   <b  attr_1="1"/>
   <b  attr_1="3">
     <c  attr_2 ="3"  attr_3 ="5"/>
     <c  attr_2 ="10"  attr_3 ="10" />
   </b>
 </a>
<a>
   <b  attr_1="1"/>
   <b  attr_1="3">
     <c  attr_2 ="3"  attr_3 ="5"/>
     <c  attr_2 ="10"  attr_3 ="12" />
   </b>
 </a>
</head>
```

The output:

```
<head>
  <a>
    <b attr_1="1"/>
    <b attr_1="3">
      <c attr_2="3" attr_3="5"/>
      <c attr_2="10" attr_3="10"/>
    </b>
  </a>
</head>
```

**Edit:** If you really want to have only `grep` statements you could use some nested greps like this, though I'd advice you to use the above, more readable solution.

```
$a->cut unless
  grep {grep {$_->att('attr_2') eq '10' and $_->att('attr_3') eq '10'}
    $_->children('c')} $a->children('b[@attr_1="3"]');
```

Comment: @vicas: [in the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig#XML::Twig) there also is an example where you only would need one `children` call, but I didn't get it to work. (it would be something like `$a->children('b[@attr_1="3"]/c[@attr_2= "10" and @attr_3= "10"]')`)